# axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...).delete(...).then(...).error is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, http-delete

I want to delete product detail #

Below API is used to call the node.js API ##

When a button is pressed then deleteApi is called then this will be matched with the backend

```
 const deleteApi = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:5000/delete-list/${id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Deleted Iteam", res);
      })
      .error((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you need to use `.catch` instead of `.error`, change it.